# Why does scrapy not use the random proxy downloader midleware?

Tags: scrapy

I am using [the following library](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) with scrapy in order to do requests from IPs through rotating proxies.

This persumably stoped working and my IP is used instead. So I am wondering if there is a fallback or if I accidently changed the config.

My settings look like this:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,

    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
PROXY_LIST = '/Users/user/test_crawl/proxy_list.txt'
PROXY_MODE = 0
```

The proxy list:

```
http://147.30.82.195:8080
http://168.183.187.238:8080
```

The traceback:

```
[scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Proxy user pass not found
2018-12-27 14:23:20 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Using proxy 
<http://168.183.187.238:8080>, 2 proxies left
2018-12-27 14:23:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/file.htm> (referer: https://www.example.com)
```

The DEBUG output of user pass not found, should be OK as it indicates that I am not using user/pass to authenticate.

The logfile on the example.com server shows my IP directly instead of the proxy IP.

This used to work, so I am wondering how to get it back working.

Comment: Does the log actually say `1109.239.251.241`? because that's not an IP address

Comment: This was a wrong proxy address, removed it but problem remains.

Comment: What was the circumstance when "it used to work"? What debugging steps have you already tried?

Comment: I reinstalled via pip: https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-proxies-tool/#description and changed the proxy list. Then it worked for a while but eventually somehow my IP got through anyway since I was getting blocked. Could it be, that there is a fallback to my IP if the proxies timeout? I would prefere to abort in that case and reinvestigate.

Comment: "there is a fallback to my IP if the proxies timeout" unknown about that, but for sure using a proxy is the non-default behavior, so the system will "fail open" in that requests will leave through your IP if something goes wrong. The way I would combat that problem is to try and run scrapy with `env http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:1" https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:1" scrapy crawl` or such, so that requests will _fail_ if they don't have their `meta["proxy"]` set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[scrapy-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) expects proxies to have a password. [If the password is empty, it ignores the proxy](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py#L100).

It should probably fail [as it does when there are not proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py#L86), but instead it does nothing, which results in no proxy being configured, and your IP being used instead.

I would say you should report the issue upstream, but the project seems dead. So, unless you are willing to fork the project and fix the issue yourself, you are out of luck.